# How to build a regexp for matching word without `"."`

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
w="abc#name,xy.abc=abc"
```

I want to replace the first and the third `"abc"` with another string. I used this code:

```
puts w.gsub(/\babc\b/,"replacer");
# => replacer#name,xy.replacer=replacer
```

where the second `"abc"` is replaced, which was not what I expected. Then I changed to the following pattern:

```
puts w.gsub(/[^\.]\babc\b/,"replacer");
# => abc#name,xy.abcreplacer
```

where the first `"abc"` is not replaced. I have no idea now how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see a difference between your first and your second pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
/\b(?<!\.)abc\b/
```

but it's a rather brute-force solution with negative look-behind.

Comment: Why is this brute force? That is the method to use for such a case. Only one thing, the `^` is wrong in your pattern, that is an anchor for the start of the string.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `(?<!\.)`? Your lookbehind matches `abc` only if it's at the start of string, right after a dot. (also be aware that lookbehind is only available in Ruby >= version 1.9)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tass but using a negative look-ahead

```
/\babc\b(?!=)/
```

Comment: It checks whether a `=` follows after `abc`. Which happens to work in your example but does not check for a dot before `abc`, so it will likely fail in other situations.

Comment: @hguser, it checks for `abc` which is not then immediately followed by an `=`. This is based on your example only and, as Tim states, it may fail in other situations. I used a look-ahead as this is available in more flavours of regex than a look-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify the regex and rely on `gsub`'s ability to take a block:

```
target = 'abc'
replacement = 'foo'
'w="abc#name,xy.abc=abc"'.gsub(/#{ target }#|=#{ target }/) { |s| s.sub(target, replacement) }
=> "w=\"foo#name,xy.abc=foo\""
```

The patterns you want are simple:

```
<target>#
=<target>
```

Find those, then do a simple string substitution.

Doing it this way isn't encapsulating all the logic into the regex, it's breaking it into two separate steps, which simplifies the logic, speeds up development time, and results in code that's easier to maintain.

Regex is a powerful tool, but sometimes you don't need a complicated pneumatic hammer, you need a small, simple, claw hammer and a screw driver.